# How can I pass named arguments to a Django view method?

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a view method with two additional parameters:

```
def foo(request, email, token):
    ...
```

And I need to use `reverse` to generate a URL:

```
    ...
    url = urlresolvers.reverse(
        'my_app.views.foo',
        kwargs={ 'token': <token>, 'email': <email> })
```

1. Is my use of `reverse` reasonable/acceptable, and
2. What does the URL pattern for `foo` look like?

Answer (score 3):

1 - Yes, as far as it goes, but of course it will fail without the urlpattern. You can use either args or kwargs, depending on your case. Here you can use args, as they are both required args from your view function.

2 - Here's a urlpattern to get you going, but the regex is only an example, as I don't know what your regex needs to be.

```
url(r'^/(?P<email>[-\w]+)/(?P<token>\d{1,2})/$', 'views.foo', name='foo'),
```

Named urls are a good pattern to get into the habit of doing. You can pass the name to the reverse function too:

```
url = urlresolvers.reverse(
    'foo',
    args=['<email>', '<token>']
```

Comment: This is a great start. Are named arguments built into the URL generally preferred over query string parameters in Django?

Comment: I'd say that's a design decision based on your site requirements. All I'll say is that I've never had to use querystrings in any of my Django sites. :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. It's up to you to write it in your URLconf.
   You might want to have a look at [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

By your question, though, it's probably better if you run through [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/). The third part explains how to write down the URL scheme for your site.

Comment: Yes I started with the docs, but that's why I'm here. I'm looking for more guidance for this specific case.